# Поиск по удалённой БД Android

Tags: android, retrofit, поиск, search, room

Всем доброго времени суток.

Меня интересует концепция работы с внешней и локальной БД во время поиска объектов.

**Задача следующая**: есть внешняя база, приложение при включении конектиться с ней, забирает 100 последних объектов, и записывает в локальную БД.

И далее вся основная работа идёт с объектами локальной БД, при синхронизации просто отсылаю новый данные и ответом получаю всё те же 100 последних объектов и переписываю локальную БД(это грубо говоря).

**Теперь появилась следующая задача:** нужно сделать фильтр с поиском по объектам, причём не только по локальной но и по всей внешней БД.

Я не совсем понимаю как мне организовать получение и хранение объектов.

Хранить на телефоне все найденные объекты нет смысла т.к. результатам поиска могут соответствовать несколько сотен старых архивных объектов, а постоянно пользователю должны отображаться только свежие объекты.

Но учитывая что с найденными объектами пользователь может работать точно также как и с обычными, получается что их тоже нужно записывать в локальную БД?

Возникает мысль сделать следующим образом: результаты поиска записывать в те же локальные таблицы но с пометками что это поиск, и при выходе со страницы поиска удалять их из локальной базы.

**Подскажите**, какие может ещё варианты есть?

Comment: У Вас предусмотрен оффлайн режим работы приложения, или доступ в интернет есть всегда?

Comment: Для оффлайн приложения придется все данные (не только 100 последних записей) скачивать и хранить в локальной БД. Если приложение "гибридное" лучше подобные запросы делать на внешнем сервере через API.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov У меня предусмотрен оффлайн режим работы приложения, понятно что при этом поиск во внешней БД не будет работать.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev У меня и так есть внешний сервер с API через которую и работаю через Retrofit, а есть какой-то вариант чтобы не хранить всё? Просто иногда кол-во скачиваемых объектов может доходить до сотен тысяч, соответственно синхронизация может затянутся, в оффлайн режиме поиск будет только по внутренней БД.

Comment: @VNprk, ну и зачем тогда скачивать эти данные то? Получили с API `JSON` - сразу вывели данные. Если нужно кэшировать запрос на случай оффлайна, то сохраняйте в локальную БД, можно прям `json` и сохранить.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Ну я в принципе и хотел узнать алгоритм действий в подобных случаях, что за чем скачивать кэшировать и обрабатывать.